# How to know that shared NFC-tag was sended to someone

Tags: nfc, phonegap-plugins, nfc-p2p

I've shared a NFC-tag on my Samsung Galaxy S3 via PhoneGap NFC Plugin ([link](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc))
Then I put the phone on reader ACR122U and send the tag. I'd like to know how to detect that the tag was read  by someone or sended to somewhere.

```
var record = ndef.mimeMediaRecord("Text", nfc.stringToBytes(id), nfc.stringToBytes(id));
    nfc.share(
        [record],
        function () {
            alert("Wrote data to tag.");
        },
        function (reason) {
            alert(reason, function () {
            }, "There was a problem");
        }
    );
```